# How addEventListener influences the onclick property of DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

```
element.onclick = function() { alert(1); } 

alert(element.onclick);
```

The above code will output `function () { alert(1); }`

Then I continue to execute the following code:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() { alert(2); }, false);
alert(element.onclick);
```

The output is still `function () { alert(1); }`

In fact when clicking on the element now, the code `addEventListener('click', function() { alert(2); }, false);` works, it means the new function `alert(2)` has written into the `onclick` property of this element. But why is the output still unchanged?

So, what I want to know is when executing `addEventListener`, how the `onclick` property changed?

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: I made a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/9sNqq/

Comment: Also - when both click handlers are added, they _both_ run, not just the second, so adding event listener does not remove previous. It seems that element.onclick is only returning the first click event function.

Comment: That will help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Notes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OnClick is a DOM Level 0 property.  AddEventListener is part of the DOM Level 2 definition.  Adding an event handler via the AddEventListener method does not change the OnClick property on the element, rather it adds the listener to a collection of event listeners on the element.  You can find out more about DOM Level 2 events at http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html.   There's also a nice article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events.

Answer (score 2):

The "onfoo" attributes are independent of the event handler management system accessed via "addEventListener()".  It's best to use one or the other, not both, and the right choice is the more flexible and unintrusive "addEventListener()" (where available).

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), "onfoo" attributes are seen as registrations in the bubbling phase.